# Snowflake TO_DATE or DATE not returning expected output from Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am setting session variable

```
SET MY_LOAD_DATE = '1999-01-01T10:10:10';

SELECT TO_DATE('1999-01-01T10:10:10.0') as d; // this command will return proper date output
```

**1999-01-01**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_ID_UPDATE(ARG STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
    $$
        var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT TO_DATE('`+ ARG +`') as d`});
        result.next();
        return result.getColumnValue(1);
        return my_date;
    $$;
    
CALL MY_ID_UPDATE($MY_LOAD_DATE);
```

Stored Procedure returns following

**Fri Jan 01 1999 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)**

What is happening inside stored procedure, why I am getting different output for same SELECT **TO_DATE** statement.

................ **Answer** ...............

I have converted string date to Date and then used toLocaleDateString method to get only date from datetime.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_ID_UPDATE(ARG STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
    $$
        var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT TO_DATE(?) as d`, binds: [ARG]});
        result.next();
        var my_date = result.getColumnValue(1);
        var d = new Date(my_date);
        return d.toLocaleDateString();
    $$;
```

This will return **1/1/1999**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"What is happening inside stored procedure, why I am getting different output for same SELECT TO_DATE statement."*

[JavaScript Data Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html#javascript-data-types):

> **SQL and JavaScript UDFs provide similar, but different, data types, based on their native data type support.** Objects within Snowflake and JavaScript are transferred using the following mappings.
>
> ...
>
> **All timestamp and date types are converted into JavaScript Date() objects. The JavaScript date type is equivalent to TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) in Snowflake SQL.**
>
> ...
>
> SQL DATE is converted to JavaScript Date representing midnight of the current day in the local time zone.

The conversions are as follow:

1. ARG: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_ID_UPDATE(ARG STRING)` as string
2. SQL: `TO_DATE(...)` as date
3. JavaScript: `result.getColumnValue(1);` Date() object
4. JavaScript stored procedure; `RETURNS STRING` Date() object converted back to string

---

Sidenote: Concatenating string to execute could lead to SQL Injection

```
var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT TO_DATE('`+ ARG +`') as d`});
```

Better way is to provide parametrized query:

```
var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT TO_DATE(?) as d`
                                ,binds: [ARG]});
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, slight error in syntax 

var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `SELECT TO_DATE(?) as d`, binds: [ARG] } );

Curly bracket should be at the last. and I had to use .toLocaleDateString() js method to get only date from the timestamp. I have added my answer below my question.